# How can I connect a server with a html file?

Tags: jsp

I'm a starter, trying to build a website. 
I've made web's mainpage with a html file and a css file. 
Trying to connect server with my html file by using tomcat. 
Is there a way?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Are you trying to ask "How do I host a static HTML file on a Tomcat server?" Do you really want to use Tomcat? It's designed for handling JSP and Servlets and while it can host static files, its not a good choice unless you are also using server-side Java.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0):

just install the tomcat, and put all the html file in one folder at the webapps folder (at tomcat installation folder) and run in browser.

:)